# Why does HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync exit Azure Web Job without running code after it?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have an Azure Web Job built using the Azure SDK whose only job is to call a web service (Web API) and then log a response based on the return value (a class). The problem is that as soon as it calls the HttpClient PostAsJsonAsync method to call the service, it exits out of the web job without executing any of the response handling. My code is:

```
public class Result
{
    // Properties ---------------------------------------------------------
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
}

public class Functions
{
    // This function will be triggered based on the schedule you have set for this WebJob
    // This function will enqueue a message on an Azure Queue called queue
    [NoAutomaticTrigger]
    public async static void ManualTrigger(TextWriter log, int value)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var rootUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("WebJobTargetUrl");
            client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(rootUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            Console.WriteLine("Call service");
            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Reminder/ProcessDueReminders", new { ItemID = 1 });
            Console.WriteLine("After service");
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Result>();
            Console.WriteLine("After result");

            if (result.Success)
                Console.WriteLine("Reminders Processed");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Reminder process error: " + result.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

and the execution logs from the portal are:
[image: Execution Logs]

I believe it has something to do with the asynchronous operation but I can't figure out a pattern that will work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Isolating-WebJobs-and-Deployment-script-issues to isolate and turn into a simpler non-WebJobs questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must define the return value of your own async method as `Task` instead of `void`.

On a related note, you should suffix the name of your method with `Async`. That's not going to solve the problem, but it indicates that you're using the async/await pattern.

Comment: Wow, that was exactly the problem! Changing void in ManualTrigger to Task fixed it. Thanks Speedbird!

Comment: @Jason You're welcome! Ask me how I knew that was the issue 

Comment: @Speedbird186 how did you know that was the issue?

Comment: Because I spent an hour looking for differences between my code and a working sample... :)

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an exception in your PostAsJsonAsync call. Try to put a try catch around it to and log the error:

```
try {
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Reminder/ProcessDueReminders", new { ItemID = 1 });
} catch (Exception ex){
       Console.WriteLine("Exception: "+ ex);
}       
Console.WriteLine("After service");
```

Comment: I actually tried that earlier and it doesn't throw an exception or anything, it just stops although the call does work. The problem is that none of the code after it runs.

Comment: It doing a web request, how long is the timeout. Maybe you can monitor the HTTP traffic.